# Recyclerview with two lists and two view holders, onCreateViewHolder and onBind not called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Hi I have the following code for my recycler view

```
package io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.ui.detail

import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.events_recycler_view_item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.images_recycler_view_item.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.news_recycler_view_item.view.*

class DetailAdapter(val context: Context, itemClickListener: DetailInteractionListener? = null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var newsItems = mutableListOf<NewsItemViewModel?>()
    private var imagesItems = mutableListOf<ImageItemViewModel?>()
    private var isNewsFragment: Boolean = false

    private var newsDetailInteractionListener: ((View) -> Unit)? = {
        if(it.tag is NewsItemViewModel){
            itemClickListener?.onNewsItemClick((it.tag as NewsItemViewModel)?.newsUrl as String)
        }
    }
    private var imagesDetailInteractionListener: ((View) ->Unit)? = {
        if(it.tag is ImageItemViewModel){
            itemClickListener?.onImageItemClick((it.tag as ImageItemViewModel)?.image as String)
        }
    }
    companion object {
        const val NEWS = 1
        const val IMAGE = 2
    }

    fun setData(newsList: List<NewsItemViewModel?>?, imagesList: List<ImageItemViewModel?>?, isNews: Boolean){
        isNewsFragment = isNews
        if(isNewsFragment) {
            newsList?.let {
                newsItems = it.toMutableList()
            }
        }
        else{
            imagesList?.let {
                this.imagesItems = it.toMutableList()
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class NewsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var article: NewsItemViewModel? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                itemView.tag = field
                field?.let {
                    Glide.with(context)
                        .load(it.thumbnail)
                        .apply {
                            RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

                        }.into(itemView.news_image)
                    itemView.headline.text = it.title
                    itemView.content.text = it.description
                }
            }
    }

    inner class ImagesViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var image: ImageItemViewModel? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                itemView.tag = field
                field?.let {
                    Glide.with(context)
                        .load(it.image)
                        .apply {
                            RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)

                        }.into(itemView.image)
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        if(viewType == NEWS){
            return NewsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.news_recycler_view_item, parent, false))
        }
        return ImagesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_recycler_view_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(isNewsFragment){
            val article = newsItems?.get(position)
            (holder as NewsViewHolder).article = article
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(newsDetailInteractionListener)
        } else {
            val image = imagesItems?.get(position)
            (holder as ImagesViewHolder).image = image
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(imagesDetailInteractionListener)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        if(isNewsFragment){
            return newsItems?.get(position)!!.viewType
        }
        return imagesItems?.get(position)!!.viewType
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return if(isNewsFragment){
            newsItems!!.size
        } else imagesItems!!.size
    }
}
```

And this is where I set the adapter in the fragment that contains it, I declared it lazily and then set it to the recyclerview's adapter after observing a live data variable from the view model.

```
package io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.ui.detail

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.R
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.repository.local.DisasterEventsRoomDatabase
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.repository.local.LocalHelperImpl
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.repository.remote.ApiHelperImpl
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.repository.remote.RemoteDataManager
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.ui.main.EventItemViewModel
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.utils.CustomViewModelFactory
import io.keepcoding.globaldisastertracker.utils.Status
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_detail.list
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_detail.loadingView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_detail.retry
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.try_again.*

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_FROM_SERVER = "FROM_SERVER"
private const val ARG_EVENT_ITEM = "EVENT_ITEM"
private const val ARG_IS_NEWS_FRAGMENT ="IS_NEWS_FRAGMENT"


/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [ListFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {
    // Fragment parameters
    private var fromServer: Boolean = false
    private var eventItem: EventItemViewModel? = null
    private var isNewsFragment: Boolean = false
    private var sharedFAB: FloatingActionButton? = null

    private var imageItems: List<ImageItemViewModel?>? = mutableListOf(null)

    private var newsItems: List<NewsItemViewModel?>? = mutableListOf(null)

    private val detailsAdapter: DetailAdapter by lazy {
        lateinit var adapter: DetailAdapter
        context?.let { context ->
            adapter = DetailAdapter(context, requireActivity() as DetailActivity)
        }
        adapter.setData(newsItems, imageItems, isNewsFragment)
        adapter
    }

    private val viewModel: DetailFragmentViewModel by lazy {
        val factory = CustomViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application,
            ApiHelperImpl(RemoteDataManager().bingSearchApi, RemoteDataManager().eonetApi),
            LocalHelperImpl(DisasterEventsRoomDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity().applicationContext))
        )
        ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(DetailFragmentViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            fromServer = it.getBoolean(ARG_FROM_SERVER)
            eventItem = it.getParcelable(ARG_EVENT_ITEM)
            isNewsFragment = it.getBoolean(ARG_IS_NEWS_FRAGMENT)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setUpListeners()
        setUpRecyclerView()
        setUpObservers()
    }

    fun setFABClickListener(fab: FloatingActionButton?){
        sharedFAB = fab
        if(fromServer){
            sharedFAB?.setOnClickListener {
                eventItem?.let { eventItem ->
                    viewModel.saveEvent(eventViewModel = eventItem)
                }
            }
        } else {
            sharedFAB?.setOnClickListener {
                eventItem?.let { eventItem ->
                    viewModel.deleteEvent(eventItem.id!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpListeners(){
        buttonRetry.setOnClickListener {
            eventItem?.let {
                fetchData(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(){
        if(isNewsFragment){ // Display linear layout with news
            list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        } else { // Display grid layout with images
            list.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
        }
        list.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    }

    private fun fetchData(event: EventItemViewModel){
        if(fromServer){
            event.title?.let { title ->
                if(isNewsFragment) viewModel.fetchApiNews(title)
                else viewModel.fetchApiImages(title)
            }
        } else {
            event.id?.let {id ->
                if(isNewsFragment) viewModel.loadNewsFromLocal(id)
                else viewModel.loadImagesFromLocal(id)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun observeImages(){
        viewModel.getImages().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { images ->
            when (images.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    imageItems = images.data
                    loadingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    list.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    list.adapter = detailsAdapter
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    loadingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    retry.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    retry.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    loadingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    list.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun observeNews(){
        viewModel.getNews().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { news ->
            when (news.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    newsItems = news.data
                    loadingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    list.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    list.adapter = detailsAdapter
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    retry.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    loadingView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    list.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    retry.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    loadingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    list.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        })
    }
    private fun setUpObservers(){
        eventItem?.let { event ->
            fetchData(event)
            if(isNewsFragment){
                observeNews()
            } else {
                observeImages()
            }
            viewModel.getSnackBar().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { snackBar ->
                when(snackBar.status) {
                    Status.SUCCESS -> Toast.makeText(requireActivity().application, snackBar.data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Status.ERROR -> Toast.makeText(requireActivity().application, snackBar.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
        }
    }


    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment ListFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(fromServer: Boolean, eventItem : EventItemViewModel, isNewsFragment: Boolean) =
            DetailFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putBoolean(ARG_FROM_SERVER, fromServer)
                    putBoolean(ARG_IS_NEWS_FRAGMENT, isNewsFragment)
                    putParcelable(ARG_EVENT_ITEM, eventItem)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

Github repo here
https://github.com/AntonioRoldan/GlobalDisasterTracker

UPDATE:
I figured out that when using FrameLayout for the fragment the recycler view is shown, but not when it is LinearLayout, also when it is FrameLayout the tab layout is covered by the recycler view any idea why this is?

Comment: Code is fine I think, I ran the code and for me, I am not getting 404 from server, I am getting this Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Resource Not Found, url=https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/news/search?q=Encinos%20Fire%20}. Please check the API.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Hi, I figured out the problem, it seems that when the fragment layout is a frame layout it shows the recycler view but not when it is linear layout, any idea why?

Comment: ah correct, try to change loadingView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE to loadingView.visibility = View.GONE, It should work. Because you are using LinearLayout and that LoadingView filled complete view, RecyclerView went down the screen, So If you give GONE it should work

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Hi, I did that and switched from FrameLayout to LinearLayout in my fragment but still have the same problem, the recycler view does not show. Also the tab layout is covered when recycler view is visible, and the appbar does not appear either.

Comment: And you are getting Data from your API?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Yes it is all correct, the data is received

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the recycler view code was fine, it was an issue with the layout.
I am including other layouts for showing a loading spinner and a retry button for failed calls and their height was match_parent, I just changed it to wrap_content in both layout files, that way I can use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout to show the recycler view under the tab layout.
Then I set retry's and loading's visibilities to GONE upon obtaining an API response